# Power analysis for drug dose study

Tags: r, statistical-power, dose-response

I am proposing a study that tests dosages of X drug as a treatment for Z disease. Basically the participant will take a starting dose of say 10mg and every two weeks the dose is upped by 10mg. The study is conducted over 10 weeks making the final dose 60mg.

The data collected will be a Likert scale questionnaire about symptoms of Z disease.

Is a power analysis needed here? The subject will be their own control.

I am thinking I can either use previous literature or Cohen's recommendation to guestimate the values needed for the power analysis.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do. If you are interested in performing null hypothesis significance testing (NHST), and you would like to know how big of a sample you will need to be able to identify a significant effect, you should do a power analysis. To me (a statistician) its kind of a strange question. Its like if you were going on a vacation road trip to the coast and you asked me if you will need to save enough money for a boat paddle. I would say: "I don't know, are you going canoeing?"

If on the other hand you just want to fit a model to describe the data, or make predictions etc, you may not be interested in NHST and you won't need to do a power analysis.

For this (and all power analyses) you need to pick the model/statistical tests which you will fit to the data. Given an effect size for a particular parameter you can then calculate power to detect such an effect size.

This sounds like a longitudinal ordered logistic regression.